# Trying to access class members through a map of pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member, stdmap

I have the following code:

```
class Thing
{
    private:
    Item item;
};

class Mgr{

   public:

   std::map<int, Item*> sps;

};



void Thing::addItemToMap(std::map<int, Item*>& sps, int i){

   sps.insert(std::make_pair(i, &(this->item)));
}


void Mgr::accessItem( int i){
    auto it = sps.find(i);
    if(it!=sps.end(){
      // it->second             is the instance of Item I inserted in the map before?
   }
}
```

will it be possible for Mgr to  retrieve the same instance of Thing->item that Thing  inserted calling "addItemToMap"  with key "i = 3") by the method "accessItem(3)"?

Comment: Yes it can but be careful with dangling pointers. You may consider using `std::shared_ptr` for the items

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing class architecture, but in your case you can rewrite your code like this and it will be the same instance:

```
class Item final {
public:
    // Some data
    int data{ 0 };
};

using ItemsMap = std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Item>>;

class Thing final {
public:
    void addItemToMap(int i, ItemsMap& items)
    {
        items.insert(std::make_pair(i, _item));
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Item> _item;
};

class Mgr final {
public:
    void accessItem(int key)
    {
        ItemsMap::const_iterator foundIt = sps.find(key);
        if (foundIt != sps.end()) {
            std::cout << foundIt->second->data << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    ItemsMap sps;
};
```